# wifi networks lost after updating

Tags: wireless

I am a total newbie with Ubuntu, so please bear with me, thanks! 
And also I apologize if the question is too long, but I just wanted to be clear about what is happening.

---

I got a hold of a Toshiba Satellite S855-S5378 with 750GB disk, 8GB ram and a Realtek **RTL8723AE** Wi-Fi card and decided to go with Ubuntu 19.04.

The installation went smooth, it detected my home Wi-Fi network, connected to it, downloaded updates on the fly, and after a while it finished and asked to reboot. I did reboot and after that, there was no internet connection. It seems that the Wi-Fi connection disappeared. I suppose that one of the updates messed up the Wi-Fi driver and now I have no connections at all.

If I go to the top right corner and click on it, it says "Wi-Fi not connected" and if I click "Select Network" there are no available networks shown to connect. During the main installation there were at least 15-20 networks (I live in a building) and it did connect because at that time it downloaded some additional software and updates.

I had no important files on the laptop, so I went and reinstalled Ubuntu again, and the behavior was exactly the same. After it finishes installing and reboot, I don't see any available networks.

---

Typed:

```
lshw -class network
```

and the card appears there with the following info:

```
description: Wireless interface

product RTL8723AE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter

vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., LTD.

physical id: 0
```

and some other information that I don't know if is relevant to include it here. So I know that the hardware is recognized, but is just not working.

---

- Am I doing something wrong?
- Can I download an updated driver for the Wi-Fi card?
- What else can I do to make it work?

---

Thanks for your help.

RPareja

---

Results of commands:

```
~$ lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3

02:00:0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723AE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:8723]

Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723AE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:0724]

Kernel driver in use: rtl8723ae

Kernel modules: rtl8723ae


~$ rfkill list all

0: TOshiba Bluetooth: Bluetooth

Soft blocked: no

Hard blocked: no

1: hc10: Bluetooth

Soft blocked: no

Hard blocked: no

2: phy0: Wireless LAN

Soft blocked: no

Hard blocked: no
```

---

> > sudo iwlist scan

enp1s0 Interface doesn't support scanning.

wlp2s0 No scan results

lo Interface doesn't support scanning.

> > dmesg | grep rtl

[12.412634] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: rtl: examining hci_ver=06 hci_rev=000b lmp_ver=06 lmp_subver=1200

[12.412636] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: rtl: loading rtl_bt/rtl8723a_fw.bin

[12.642649] rtl8723a Using firmware rtlwifi/rtl8723fw_b.bin

[12.665843] ieee802111 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'rtl_rc'

[12.666019] rtlwifi: rtlwifi: wireless switch is on

[12.763393] rtl8723ae 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0

---

no error or warnings after both commands, but the result for scan is the same as before:

> > sudo iwlist scan

enp1s0 Interface doesn't support scanning.

wlp2s0 No scan results

lo Interface doesn't support scanning.

what troubles me is that during the installation the wifi worked fine.    :(

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal commands: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` and also: `rfkill list all` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Looks good so far. Let's also see in an edit: `sudo iwlist scan` as well as: `dmesg | grep rtl`

Comment: Please try: `sudo modprobe -r rtl8723ae` and next: `sudo modprobe -v rtl8723ae swenc=1 ips=0 fwlps=0` Now does it scan? `sudo iwlist scan`

Comment: hi chili555, same result after the scan

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 19.04 did not recognized Realtek 8723DE.  I tried the Ubuntu Desktop Guide procedure first but I was not able to solve the problem and it should be the first place to start to try to solve problems first.
I was able to solve it with the following procedure from this link:
https://ibcomputing.com/install-rtl8723de-realtek-d723-ubuntu-18-04/

```
$ git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
$ cd rtlwifi_new
$ git checkout extended
$ sudo make install
$ sudo modprobe -r rtl8723de
$ sudo modprobe rtl8723de
```

Wireless work without rebooting, but if it this not happens to you follow with:

```
$ sudo -i
# reboot
```

Answer (score 0):

I got an update on my ubuntu installed it and I had this problem too but after I switched off my laptop and powered on it has been solved. My modem is the same RTL8723AE.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write an answer, however I feel this should've been a comment instead: Reading the question it seems likely that the OP has already power-cycled (at least rebooted) their computer but the problem remained. So I'd suggest to write a comment under the question asking whether power-cycling was actually tried, then either edit or delete this answer according to what they say.