# No wifi connections visible after upgrade to 20.04

Tags: wireless

I just upgraded my msi ge60 from 18.04 to 20.04 ubuntu. Upgrade have no error. But after reboot, i see no wifi hotspot.

Computer informations:

uname -a

```
Linux topinambour 5.4.0-42-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 10 00:24:02 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

ip a

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 8c:89:a5:0c:fc:e5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.40/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp3s0
       valid_lft 86127sec preferred_lft 86127sec
    inet6 fe80::7861:f34c:fa5d:3ffe/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlp5s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 24:0a:64:4a:a1:ad brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: anbox0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether f6:26:fc:62:4b:c3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.250.1/24 scope global anbox0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::f426:fcff:fe62:4bc3/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:fc:5e:67:2c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

lshw -C network

```
*-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       produit: Killer E220x Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       fabricant: Qualcomm Atheros
       identifiant matériel: 0
       information bus: pci@0000:03:00.0
       nom logique: enp3s0
       version: 13
       numéro de série: 8c:89:a5:0c:fc:e5
       taille: 1Gbit/s
       capacité: 1Gbit/s
       bits: 64 bits
       horloge: 33MHz
       fonctionnalités: pm pciexpress msi msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration : autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=alx duplex=full ip=192.168.1.40 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       ressources : irq:19 mémoire:f7a00000-f7a3ffff portE/S:d000(taille=128)
  *-network
       description: Interface réseau sans fil
       produit: RTL8723AE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       fabricant: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       identifiant matériel: 0
       information bus: pci@0000:05:00.0
       nom logique: wlp5s0
       version: 00
       numéro de série: 24:0a:64:4a:a1:ad
       bits: 64 bits
       horloge: 33MHz
       fonctionnalités: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration : broadcast=yes driver=rtl8723ae driverversion=5.4.0-42-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       ressources : irq:17 portE/S:c000(taille=256) mémoire:f7800000-f7803fff
  *-network:0
       description: Ethernet interface
       identifiant matériel: 2
       nom logique: anbox0
       numéro de série: f6:26:fc:62:4b:c3
       fonctionnalités: ethernet physical
       configuration : broadcast=yes driver=bridge driverversion=2.3 firmware=N/A ip=192.168.250.1 link=yes multicast=yes
  *-network:1
       description: Ethernet interface
       identifiant matériel: 3
       nom logique: docker0
       numéro de série: 02:42:fc:5e:67:2c
       fonctionnalités: ethernet physical
       configuration : broadcast=yes driver=bridge driverversion=2.3 firmware=N/A ip=172.17.0.1 link=no multicast=yes
```

dmesg | grep -i rtl

```
[    5.413316] rtl8723ae: Using firmware rtlwifi/rtl8723fw_B.bin
[    5.438434] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'rtl_rc'
[    5.448116] rtlwifi: rtlwifi: wireless switch is on
[    6.272162] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: examining hci_ver=06 hci_rev=000b lmp_ver=06 lmp_subver=1200
[    6.272163] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8723a_fw.bin
[    6.970210] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: fw version 0x0e3da5b1
[    9.331547] rtl8723ae 0000:05:00.0 wlp5s0: renamed from wlan0
[  278.889060] rtlwifi: rtlwifi: wireless switch is on
[  280.164103] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: examining hci_ver=06 hci_rev=000b lmp_ver=06 lmp_subver=1200
[  280.164107] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8723a_fw.bin
[  280.835118] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: fw version 0x0e3da5b1
```

How can i fix it ? Thank's !

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `dmesg | grep -i rtl` terminal command.

Comment: Question edited. Note: Suspend then wakeup my laptop make wifi back angain, like in https://askubuntu.com/a/1237471/29273

Comment: Then it is some bug with suspend.

Comment: Suspend fix the wifi bug in that case, no ? :p

Comment: Wifi works. If it doesn't work again, then report a bug.

Comment: Wifi doesn't work at startup. I need to suspend once after start my computer.

Comment: Anyway the log is needed when it doesn't work.