# Lost my Wifi connection after running last ubuntu update

Tags: wireless, updates, realtek, secure-boot

I have a problem like the one explain in this post : [wifi networks lost after updating](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1155961/wifi-networks-lost-after-updating)

I don't know how to solve it. I use Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS on a Lenovo ThinkPad E15 with a dual boot (windows/Ubuntu).

My problem occur after my last update and now, no Wifi detected at all.

Here some info :

uname :

```
michel@michel-ThinkPad-E15:~$ uname -a

Linux michel-ThinkPad-E15 5.4.0-42-generic #46~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 10 07:21:24 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

rfkill :

```
michel@michel-ThinkPad-E15:~$ rfkill list all

0: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
   Soft blocked: yes
   Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
   Soft blocked: no
   Hard blocked: no
```

lspci :

```
michel@michel-ThinkPad-E15:~$ lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3

05:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:c822]
Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:c123]
Kernel driver in use: rtw_pci
Kernel modules: rtwpci
```

nmcli :

```
michel@michel-ThinkPad-E15:~$ nmcli dev wifi list

IN-USE  SSID  MODE  CHAN  RATE  SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY
michel@michel-ThinkPad-E15:~$ dmesg | grep -e rtw
[    3.846786] rtw_pci 0000:05:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0003)
[    3.846812] rtw_pci 0000:05:00.0: Direct firmware load for rtw88/rtw8822c_wow_fw.bin failed with error -2
[    3.846814] rtw_pci 0000:05:00.0: failed to request firmware
[    3.847210] rtw_pci 0000:05:00.0: Firmware version 5.0.0, H2C version 14
[    4.108806] rtw_pci 0000:05:00.0 wlp5s0: renamed from wlan0
[    4.922547] rtw_pci 0000:05:00.0: failed to wait firmware completion
[    4.931715] rtw_pci 0000:05:00.0: failed to wait firmware completion
[    4.935412] rtw_pci 0000:05:00.0: failed to wait firmware completion
[   15.015312] rtw_pci 0000:05:00.0: failed to wait firmware completion
[   15.019406] rtw_pci 0000:05:00.0: failed to wait firmware completion
[   25.020507] rtw_pci 0000:05:00.0: failed to wait firmware completion
[   25.024711] rtw_pci 0000:05:00.0: failed to wait firmware completion
[   35.023713] rtw_pci 0000:05:00.0: failed to wait firmware completion
[   35.027775] rtw_pci 0000:05:00.0: failed to wait firmware completion
[   45.016491] rtw_pci 0000:05:00.0: failed to wait firmware completion
[   45.020322] rtw_pci 0000:05:00.0: failed to wait firmware completion
[   55.021730] rtw_pci 0000:05:00.0: failed to wait firmware completion
[   55.025759] rtw_pci 0000:05:00.0: failed to wait firmware completion
[  319.399719] rtw_pci 0000:05:00.0: failed to wait firmware completion
[  319.404033] rtw_pci 0000:05:00.0: failed to wait firmware completion
```

Can anyone help me ?

I have disable my secureboot after i read that it can be a problem with unsigned version of an updated wifi driver (secureboot need signed module i think), but no success for me.

Can anyone say me if i can try what is proposed here : https://medium.com/@vovaprivalov/fixing-problem-with-missing-wifi-adapter-on-ubuntu-18-04-dec50879a47e   (i have don't try it cause i am not sure it's the same path for me ... don't want to crash my system more than now !)

(sorry for my bad english)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update `linux-firmware`. The 18.04 repo doesn't have the `rtw88/rtw8822c_wow_fw.bin` file yet.

You can safely install the `linux-firmware` from the 20.04 repo, because now you have the same firmware. Run in a terminal:

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.187.2_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux-firmware_1.187.2_all.deb
```

Comment: Thanks Pilot6, i recover my wifi connection.

Comment: ... but after this i re enable my secure boot (this seem to be ok). But now, after i run the Ubuntu Update software, the message "Le téléchargement des informations du dépôt a échoué" ... i think i can translate by "Failed to download repository information". I will search the web for this new problem but if you have a suggestion for this, you are welcome.

Comment: Ok, sorry it's my first time here. For the rest of the problem (don't know if it is link to the my first problem ... may be !), what is the best way ?  i try to do "sudo apt-get clean" and after "sudo apt-get update" but the last one fail ...    "E: Le fichier « Release » pour http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-security/InRelease n'est pas encore valable (invalide pendant encore 2h 7min 45s). Les mises à jour depuis ce dépôt ne s'effectueront pas.                   i can translate with "E: The file «Release» is not valable. Update from this repository don't work"

Comment: You can get English output by `LANG=C sudo apt-get update`, etc. Please ask a new question. Comments are not for asking questions. This is not a discussion forum.

Comment: Ok, i will continu to search for my next problem, thanks a lot for your help Pilot6